# Software to enable Direct Connect with banks

Tags: web-development, api, web-services, finance

There are many online personal finance programs that have a feature of directly connecting to a multitude of financial institutions to pull transactions into their programs.

They are clearly not all writing their own.

What software (quite possibly it is more Software as a Service) is available to accomplish this?

I am a software developer looking to integrate such functionality into my own application.

Comment: I would look into the source of those pages which offer those services, and I'm sure you'll find some sort of API, REST or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I have found two options.

1. [Plaid](https://www.plaid.com/)
2. [Yodlee](https://www.yodlee.com)

The rumors on the web are that Yodlee is much more expensive.